# Can't figure out a step in a binomial theorem example

Tags: binomial-theorem

today I was practicing math and I've come to a example where I can't figure out how did they got this result.
Here you have the example:
[image]

and this is the step which I don't get:

[image]

Comment: use induction on integer n

Comment: @AbdallahHammam on which n exactly?

Comment: $n$  of the right hand side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S=\{0,1,\ldots,2n\}$. Let $\mathscr{A}_k$ be the family of subsets $A$ of $S$ such that

- $|A|=n+1$;
- $k+m\in A$; and
- $|\{a\in A:a<k+m\}|=k$.

Because it contains $0$, $S$ has $k+m$ elements less than $k+m$, so there are $\binom{k+m}k$ ways to choose the $k$ elements of $A$ smaller than $k+m$. There are $2n-(k+m)$ elements of $S$ larger than $k+m$, so there are $\binom{2n-(k+m)}{n-k}$ ways to choose the rest of $A$. Thus,

$$|\mathscr{A}_k|=\binom{k+m}k\binom{2n-(k+m)}{n-k}=\binom{k+m}k\binom{2n-k-m}{n-m}\;,$$

since $2n-k-m-(n-k)=n-m$. $|S|=2n+1$, so $S$ has $\binom{2n+1}{n+1}$ subsets of cardinality $n+1$, and we have

$$\sum_k\binom{k+m}k\binom{2n-k-m}{n-m}=\sum_k|\mathscr{A}_k|=\binom{2n+1}{n+1}\;.$$

Finally,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}\sum_k\binom{k+m}k\binom{2n-k-m}{n-m}&=\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}\binom{2n+1}{n+1}\\
&=\frac{(n!)^2(2n+1)!}{(2n)!(n+1)!n!}\\
&=\frac{2n+1}{n+1}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: brillian answer ... thanks prof scott

Comment: @ILoveMath: You're welcome.

Comment: Thank you very much! @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Dragan: You’re very welcome!